# password_verify not matching after writing to database

Tags: php, mysqli, password-hash

I think my problem is environmental, but I have tapped everything I can think of to find it.  The code was working fine 3 weeks ago, and suddenly stopped a few days ago.  I haven't updated the O/S or PHP in that timeframe.

I'm using password_hash to create a password from a $_POST variable, and then writing it to a MySQL database field (set to varchar(255)).  After the problem came up I added test code to do password_verify on the variable in memory before writing to the database, and then re-read the value from the database after writing it there.  In both cases it returns as a match. However, any other page trying to run password_verify returns as a mismatch.  I have captured the initial hash and visually compared it to the value in the database and they are identical.  Both servers (the one that generates the hash and the one that reads it when the user logs in are both running the same version of php (5.6.9-0+deb8u1).

Here's my complete code in it's current state of debugging.  In the code below the commented out line using PASSWORD_DEFAULT is what I was originally using.  I tried BCRYPT option just to see if it would fix it.  I also tried putting $_POST['password'] into a variable instead of calling it directly, and wrapping a trim around it.  Everything seems fine until I leave this page and try from another page.  I have also checked the items discussed in other posts on the web.

```
//USER DOES NOT EXIST 
mysqli_close($con);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    $error = true;
}
// New user - add them to database
echo "Creating your account. <br>";
$pwd = $_POST['password'];
//$password = password_hash(trim($_POST['password']), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);    
$password = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);   
echo $password . '<br>';


$sel = 'CALL sp_add_user("'. $_POST['firstname'] . '","'. $_POST['lastname'] . '","'. $_POST['email1'] . 
    '","'. $_POST['city'] . '","'. $_POST['country'] . '","'. $password . '","'. $timestamp . '")';

$con=mysqli_connect($conip,$dbuser,$dbpw,$mgrdb);
if(!mysqli_query($con, $sel))
{
    echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
}
else{
    mysqli_close($con);
    //verify the password in the DB is good
    $sel='CALL sp_get_pwd("' . $_POST['email1'] . '")';
    //echo $sel;
    $con=mysqli_connect($conip,$dbuser,$dbpw,$mgrdb);
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sel);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $dbpwd = $row['password'];
        }
    }
    echo $dbpwd . '<br>';
    if(password_verify(trim($_POST['password']), $dbpwd)){echo 'Match<br>'; } else { echo 'Match failed<br> ';} 
    mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Sidenote question: Why so many `$con=mysqli_connect($conip,$dbuser,$dbpw,$mgrdb);` and `mysqli_close($con);`?

Comment: A way to debug it is `var_dump`ing your `$pwd` and your `$dbpwd`, checking if they match visually.

Comment: Also, I think it's good if you verify your PHP and database charset definitions.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I'll look into these.  @Fred  the connection & close was part of what I was trying for debugging ... wasn't sure if some sort of cached goo was happening, so I figured I'd guarantee fresh db connections for each step. (I know needless CPU time, etc. but I'll clean up when I get it working again).

Comment: @Aedix Rhinedale: Verified my charsets: in php.ini default charset is UTF8, all HTML headers also UTF8, and MySQL fields in this database are UTF8_unicode_ci.  I var_dumped $pwd & $dbpwd - they are identical.  I built a simple page to retrieve the password hash, var_dumped it out, and it is also identical.  On the page the writes it to the database, (existing in the above code) I do test it with password_verify after I write it to the database and it matches just fine.  I'm really stumped why every attempt after that results in a mismatch.

Comment: It's something with my post data.  I created a page with hard-coded values and it works fine.  Thanks for the idea @Aedix Rhinedale.  Once I track down what it is and fix it I'll update this ... if I get stuck I may bug you folks again! ;-)

Comment: Did you check `$dbpwd` for hidden whitespaces (you could use the `strlen($dbpwd)` function)?

Comment: If it's an issue with POST variables, then show those. (Common issue: magic quotes, albeit that might just save you from lack of escaping here). It's also unclear if the stored procedure didn't mangle anything. Please use a few MarkDown lists to add further details. (Long walls of text are hard to consume.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simulated your code without database and form fetching, and it runs ok. It means there's something wrong either with your database or with your POST fields.

```
// New user - add them to database
echo "Creating your account. <br>";
$pwd = '12345';
//$password = password_hash(trim($_POST['password']), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);    
$password = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);   
echo $password . '<br>';

$dbpwd = $password;

echo $dbpwd . '<br>';
if(password_verify(trim($pwd), $dbpwd))
{
    echo 'Match<br>';
}
else
{
    echo 'Match failed<br> ';
}
```

Output:

```
Creating your account.
$2y$10$iw6fSApO7Ok0ySZ.OsQqbe.DpVrvzJ86ZYIsWYg5060hyXbBYEiee
$2y$10$iw6fSApO7Ok0ySZ.OsQqbe.DpVrvzJ86ZYIsWYg5060hyXbBYEiee
Match
```

Use `var_dump` on your hashed `$password` var **before** the INSERT, then again with your `$dbpwd` **after** the SELECT and see if you get anything wrong. Also, check your PHP project scripts and your database schema for conflicting charset definitions.

Comment: Thx - I'll check this out.

Comment: As per my previous comment, it's some sort of $_POST data issue.  I'm flagging this answer as the solution, but all of @Aedix's responses contributed.  If I'm still stuck I'll post a new question related to $_POST data issues. Thanks!